# What level can a bounty hunter dual-wield pistols?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Like the question states, I was wondering at what level I would be able to dual-wield pistols as a Bounty Hunter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Level 10, only if you choose mercenary as your advanced class.